# Was Max Born the first to notice a connection between quantum mechanics and randomness?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, history, probability, born-rule

Max Born introduced the Born Rule in a paper from 1926. But was this really the first time that a connection between quantum mechanics and randomness was noticed?

Today, quantum mechanics and randomness seem to be so closely connected that it's hard to imagine that 21 years should have past between Einstein's 1905 paper on the photoelectric effect, and the realization that randomness might be involved if "energy is exchanged only in discrete amounts".

Comment: There is no randomness in quantum mechanics. What is there is called "uncertainty". The difference between the two is enormous: it's one imaginary unit in the equations of motion, which changes absolutely everything. For starters, there wouldn't be a universe without it... one can't build a non-empty universe on "randomness".

Comment: @CuriousOne - what are you talking about? In quantum mechanics, the value of a measured quantity does not have a cause, it's a random variable distributed according to the Born rule. If your physical theory has a causal explanation for the actual outcome of the measurement, then your theory is something other than quantum mechanics.

Comment: As for the remarks about *i* and the existence of the universe, I can only guess at what you have in mind.

Comment: @MitchellPorter: Where did I say anything about causes for a single measurement? I said that there is no randomness in quantum mechanics, instead there is uncertainty. The two are not the same, even though many seemingly can't be talked out of mistaking them for each other. I would ask you to take a look at the  dynamics of quantum systems. They are perfectly causal, it's simply the outcome of an individual measurement which reduces the state of the system to a classical variable that simply can not represent the full state of the system, that is not fully determined.

Comment: @Mitchellporter: Nothing more and nothing less than the impossibility to reduce matter to classical physics. Either you have quantum mechanics, and then you can have matter, or you can have classical mechanics, and then you won't have nothing at all. I thought that was clear?

Comment: @CuriousOne: If "state" fundamentally is a random variable/probability distribution, I don't see how you can say "there's no randomness in QM". Just having a deterministic evolution of random variables does not eliminate the fact that they're random variables.

Comment: @R..: Where do you all get this idea from, that the state in quantum mechanics is a random variable? Certainly not good textbooks on quantum mechanics. The state in QM is a complex number, a complex vector or a complex operator, all of which follow a perfectly smooth dynamic. Can you show me a textbook on probability theory, where random variables are smooth complex functions?

Comment: @CuriousOne: you write "[quantum systems] are perfectly causal...", but then "the outcome of an individual measurement... is not fully determined". The last part is where randomness enters, according to quantum theory.

Comment: @MitchellPorter: That's where uncertainty enters, according to quantum theory. Randomness only enters according to talking heads of the general press who have either not taken a QM class or who didn't understand it.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Suppose I'm going to measure some observable and I start with a superposition of eigenstates, |x>+|y>. According to QM, the system can start in the state |x>+|y>, and then end up in the state |x> or the state |y>. If it was completely deterministic, there would only be one possible end state.

Comment: @MitchellPorter: Yes, that's called uncertainty, not randomness. Please consult a stochastics textbook on how randomness works and try to find a common basis for uncertainty and randomness. You won't. Random variables do not show interference phenomena and they do not occupy tensor product spaces. Indeed, random processes are subject to very general central limit theorems which show that multiple random processes will almost always reduce to a trivial Gaussian distribution. Quantum systems don't do that. Please look at chemistry and biology to see what quantum systems do, instead.

Comment: @CuriousOne - orthodox QM for more than 80 years has been, the wavefunction evolves deterministically according to Schrodinger's equation, *until an observation is made*, at which point the wavefunction jumps RANDOMLY to some eigenstate of the observable, with a probability equal to ... blah blah, I'm sure you know this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly not. I was already known for a long time that certain microscopic phenomena were best described by probabilistic theories, the prime example being radioactivity. Even on the classical level, statistical mechanics (canonical example: Brownian motion) had prepared some physicists to relax their classical conceptions of reality.

However, it was of course not clear *how exactly* quantum phenomena and 'randomness' are connected until the advent of quantum mechanics and Born's interpretation of $|\Psi(x,t)|^2$. The small book ['Uncertainty'](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1400079969) is largely dedicated to the development of these concepts in the late 19th/early 20th century, and is a nice read even though it does not really get down to the nitty gritty of the technical details.